# Access all websites on a server via a shared domain

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, url, virtualhost

My setup is:

- Nginx(80) as a transparent proxy
- Apache(81) as back-end web server

The paths to each domain on the server are like this:

```
/var/www/$username/data/www/$domainname
```

Of course to access the files you need to use the domain name of each website. But I want a way to access all the domains using an URL like this:

```
http://dm.some.com/clientdomain.com
```

How can I do this? This URL will be used to access ONLY static files, so I think it will be best to use Nginx for this.

Comment: How does $username map to $domainname?

Comment: $username is just the username of the user and it can be anything. A user can have many domains and $domainname is a folder named  clientdomain.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is determining the username for a specific domain. Actually getting nginx to search through all the usernames to find this is tricky and not optimal. There are two approaches I can think of.

#### Symlink all domains into one directory

Create a directory with symlinks to every domain, for example:

```
/srv/www/all/example.com -> /srv/www/alice/data/www/example.com
/srv/www/all/example.org -> /srv/www/alice/data/www/example.org
/srv/www/all/example.net -> /srv/www/bob/data/www/example.net
```

And then just setup a virtual host in nginx with `/srv/www/all` as the root.

#### Manually configure the mapping in nginx

The [map](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMapModule) module is probably the simplest to maintain.

```
map $uri $username {
    /example.com    alice;
    /example.org    alice;
    /example.net    bob;
}

root /srv/www;
rewrite ^/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /$username/data/www/$1/$2 last;
```